# Visualization chart not being displayed

Tags: visualforce, javascript, ajax

I'm using the code below but it is no showing any chart, is there an obvious reason why?

```
 < script type="text/javascript" src="http://google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script src="/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
      formatCurrencyLabel = function( value ){
        return "$" + String(value);
      }

      google.load("visualization" , "1" , {package:["ColumnChart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(Chart);

      function Chart(){

        data.addColumn(‘string’, ‘Timeframe’);
        data.addColumn(‘number’, ‘Gold’);
        data.addColumn(‘number’, ‘Platinum’);
        data.addColumn(‘number’, ‘Millinium’);

        sforce.connection.sessionId = ‘{!$Api.Session_ID}’;
        var date = new Date();
        var dateMin = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -13);
        var date = new Date();
        var dateMax = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() +1);
        var soql = "Select id,name,GOLD_Policies_InForce__c, MNS_Policies_InForce__c, PLAT_Policies_InForce__c, Producer_Name__c, Type__c, Producer_Code__c  from Analytics__c where Producer_Name__c ='TestABC2' and Period__c ='21' and CreatedDate <" + convertToISO(dateMax) + " and convertToISO(CreatedDate) > " + dateMin + " Order by CreatedDate asc ";


var result = sforce.connection.query(soql);
            var it = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(result);
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                var record = it.next();
                data.addRow(['record.CreatedDate'{
                    v:parseFloat(record.PLAT_Policies_InForce__c),
                    f:formatCurrencyLabel(record.PLAT_Policies_InForce__c)
                  },{
                    v:parseFloat(record.PLAT_Policies_InForce__c),
                    f:formatCurrencyLabel(record.PLAT_Policies_InForce__c)
                  },{
                    v:parseFloat(record.GOLD_Policies_InForce__c),
                    f: formatCurrencyLabel(record.GOLD_Policies_InForce__c)
                  }
                ]);
            }
            var options = {'title':'Policies Inforce Rolling 13 Months' , legend: 'left' ,
                          'width':560,
                          'height':228,
                          'colors' : ['green','orange','#B5C5D7']
                          };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            chart.draw(data , options);
        };
        </script>
        <body><div id="chart"></div></body>
```

I am getting error message like.

> uncaught exception: {faultcode:'sf:INVALID_FIELD',
>   faultstring:'INVALID_FIELD: ='TestABC2' and Period__c ='21' and
>   CreatedDate <'1367152811508' and ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:214 value of
>   filter criterion for field 'CreatedDate' must be of type dateTime and
>   should not be enclosed in quotes',
>   detail:{InvalidFieldFault:{exceptionCode:'INVALID_FIELD',
>   exceptionMessage:' ='TestABC2' and Period__c ='21' and CreatedDate
>   <'1367152811508'

Comment: could you check than  sforce.connection.sessionId is getting the right value ? Also would be useful to check record value by console. 
In addition, you don't have to add < body > tag in VF

Comment: btw, try to resume the topic of your question in subject, and explain as best as you can your question in the body.

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console? That'd be the first thing to check

Comment: I am getting error message like. uncaught exception: {faultcode:'sf:INVALID_FIELD', faultstring:'INVALID_FIELD: ='TestABC2' and Period__c ='21' and CreatedDate <'1367152811508' and ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:214 value of filter criterion for field 'CreatedDate' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes', detail:{InvalidFieldFault:{exceptionCode:'INVALID_FIELD', exceptionMessage:' ='TestABC2' and Period__c ='21' and CreatedDate <'1367152811508'

Comment: and ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:214 value of filter criterion for field 'CreatedDate' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes', row:'1', column:'214', }, }, }

Comment: those comments are helpful, but very hard to read, instead edit the question to add the useful info.  The more effort you put into making your question concise, too the point, legible, and with full details, the better your answers are going to be

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, you only have to set `dateMax` and `dateMin` as timestamps format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ. Just **removing** the extra **quotes** and format the date vars it should work.

There your have a js function to convert to iso format https://stackoverflow.com/a/6272061/356042

Change this

```
 var result = sforce.connection.query("Select id,name,GOLD_Policies_InForce__c," +
            "MNS_Policies_InForce__c, PLAT_Policies_InForce__c, " +
            " Producer_Name__c, Type__c, Producer_Code__c " +
            "from Analytics__c " +
            "where Producer_Name__c ='TestABC2' and Period__c ='21' " +
            "and CreatedDate <'" + dateMax + "' and CreatedDate >'" + dateMin + "'" +
            " Order by CreatedDate asc");
```

by this

```
 var soql = "Select id,name,GOLD_Policies_InForce__c, MNS_Policies_InForce__c, PLAT_Policies_InForce__c, Producer_Name__c, Type__c, Producer_Code__c  from Analytics__c where Producer_Name__c ='TestABC2' and Period__c ='21' and CreatedDate <" + convertToISO(dateMax) + " and convertToISO(CreatedDate) > " + dateMin + " Order by CreatedDate asc ";

console.log(soql);
var result = sforce.connection.query(soql);
```

Check the formed soql by console, and try it into Developer console.

Comment: It showing the error  SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]  

CreatedDate <" + dateMax + " and CreatedDate >" + dateMin + " +

Comment: hmm, I don't see any missing quote. I edited my answer, try this form

Comment: I have tried with that soql .And showing error like    SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]  

console.log(soql);  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, remove the console.log(soql); or change , by ;

Comment: It showing the error      uncaught exception: {faultcode:'sf:MALFORMED_QUERY', faultstring:'MALFORMED_QUERY: 
Period__c ='21' and CreatedDate <1367157336106 and CreatedDate >
                                 ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:228
For input string: "1367157336106"', detail:{MalformedQueryFault:{exceptionCode:'MALFORMED_QUERY', exceptionMessage:'
Period__c ='21' and CreatedDate <1367157336106 and CreatedDate >

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, The SQOL datetime right format is ISO... check the function i've added to the answer

Comment: ReferenceError: convertToISO is not defined Is the error

Comment: of course, You have to implement it using the link I posted you

Comment: I don't find the suitable answer there for this date format

Comment: @M.Reddy you've really got to put some more elbow grease into this.  It doesn't seem like you're trying to work out anything on your own.

Comment: I am new to google visualization. And the task was in crucial stage to move to production. I tried but I am unable to solve the problem. And see the date fields format in the above code. Please help me.